# First entity within NSSet has shorter ID and doesn't retain value changes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uikit

I have two entities, `House` and `Room`. Mutiple `Room`s are connected to `Home` through the attribute `rooms` within `House`.

Within Swift if I get all members of the `rooms` like so `parentHouse?.rooms?.allObjects as! [Room]` and an array is returned that looks like so...

```
[<Room: 0x1c4286360> (entity: Room; id: 0x1c423c1c0 <x-coredata:///Room/t7A9E5891-F454-496B-A288-8D965C6722842> ; data: {
    room = "Bedroom";
    index = 0;
    house = "0xd000000000580000 <x-coredata://DA7D7CD6-F078-49DF-8684-EDD51D3D0D90/House/p22>";
}), <Room: 0x1c028bbd0> (entity: Room; id: 0xd000000000680002 <x-coredata://DA7D7CD6-F078-49DF-8684-EDD51D3D0D90/Room/p26> ; data: {
    room = "Kitchen";
    index = 0;
    house = "0xd000000000580000 <x-coredata://DA7D7CD6-F078-49DF-8684-EDD51D3D0D90/House/p22>";
}), <Room: 0x1c028c080> (entity: Room; id: 0xd000000000740002 <x-coredata://DA7D7CD6-F078-49DF-8684-EDD51D3D0D90/Room/p29> ; data: {
    room = "Bathroom";
    index = 1;
    house = "0xd000000000580000 <x-coredata://DA7D7CD6-F078-49DF-8684-EDD51D3D0D90/House/p22>";
})]
```

The problem I'm facing is that once the first entity's attribute `index` has been set, it cannot be changed again despite all other entity's `index` being properly changed. I've set `index` as transient and yet the issue still persists.

Upon close inspection it would appear that the first item has a different looking id than the others, maybe this comes into play?

What is the issue here and how can I change the `index` attribute of the first item? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I moved to using an `NSOrderedSet` and I recommend anyone attempting to use an ordering index alongside a Core Data item to do so too.